# noEntryText attribute for ComboBoxes won't apply for Custom Fields?

Tags: rally

I'm currently working with comboboxes and filters to implement an option to select all instances of a desired field. With that said, I know to use the `noEntryText` attribute to set what originally defaults to "--No Entry--" as "All". However, the changes do not seem to apply when I use this on **custom** fields provided by my Web Services API (those fields with the "c_" before them).

Strangely enough though, this convention works for other fields that I use that do not have the "c_" before them. So is this a known defect just for custom fields or is there a workaround to this issue?

Comment: can you post some of your code creating the combobox so i can see what you're doing?

Answer (score 0):

I filed a defect that replacing noEntryText to a custom value works for `rallyfieldvaluecombobox` for standard fields, but not custom fields.
If `rallyfieldvaluecombobox` uses a standard field, e.g. Environment, then no entry can be replaced successfully:

[image]

Here is the js file:

```
Ext.define('CustomApp', {
    extend: 'Rally.app.App',
    componentCls: 'app',
    launch: function() {
        this.add({
            xtype: 'rallyfieldvaluecombobox',
            itemId: 'aBox',
            fieldLabel: 'Filter by filed:',
            model: 'defect',
            //field: 'c_CustomBox',
            field: 'Environment',
            noEntryText: 'All',
            useNullForNoEntryValue: true,
            allowNoEntry: true,
            listeners: {
                select: this._onSelect,
                ready: this._onLoad,
                scope: this
            }
        });
    },
    _onLoad: function() {
        this.add({
            xtype: 'rallygrid',
            columnCfgs: [
                'FormattedID',
                'Name',
                //'c_CustomBox'
                'Environment'
            ],
            context: this.getContext(),
            storeConfig: {
                model: 'defect',
                filters: [this._getStateFilter()]
            },
            width: 500
        });
    },
    _getStateFilter: function() {
        if (!this.down('#aBox').getValue()) { 
            return 1;
        }
        else{
            return {
                //property: 'c_CustomBox',
                property: 'Environment',
                operator: '=',
                value: this.down('#aBox').getValue()
            };
        }
    },
    _onSelect: function() {
        var grid = this.down('rallygrid'),
            store = grid.getStore();

        store.clearFilter(true);
        store.filter(this._getStateFilter());
    }
});
```

If the same `rallyfieldvaluecombobox` uses a custom field, then no entry string cannot be replaced:

[image]

In both cases the functionality of replacing the filtering behavior works fine.